# Counting the number of cells in a matrix using Python

Tags: python, matrix

I have a file that contains a matrix the first row shows the number of rows 3, columns 5.

```
    3 5 
    TTTTT
    TMMMT
    TTTTT
```

I am writing a python program to divide the columns and sum up the number of cells,

```
    TT
    TM
    TT

    total number = 6
```

the second two

```
    TT
    MM
    TT
    total number= 6
```

and the final one

```
    T
    T
    T

    total number = 3
```

The code I have so far

```
 rows = []
with open('example.in') as fp: #the file name is example.in
    for line in fp:
     rows.append(line.strip()) #removes white spaces 

    for i , rowi in enumerate(rows[1:]): #slices out the first row
      print(len(rowi))
```

the output

```
    5
    5
    5
```

It is adding up the number of cells in each row.
I am new in python programming.

Comment: By what rule are you "dividing the columns?"

Comment: I am dividing the rows not columns

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this?

```
def count_cells_row(file_in):
    """
    generator to count cells per row

    file_in -- fileobject containing matrix
    """
    for row in file_in:
        row = row.strip()
        if row:
            yield len(row)

with open('/path/to/file') as file_in:
    ncells = sum([i for i in count_cells_row(file_in)])

print (ncells)
```

So I first make a generator that produces the length of the rows per iteration.
Then I make a list of these values by list comprehension ([i for i in count_cells_row(file_in)]), this is another way of making a loop.
The results of that will be in your case [5, 5, 5].

I use the python function `sum` to calculate the sum of these values.